# How to build dynamic sql query in python and use executemany() to insert?

Tags: python, mysql

In my code, I am selecting 10 000 rows of data from a MySQL table and building a list of 100 rows to insert at a time. I am inserting the data into a table on another server. I want to be able to use this code for tables with different values and columns. How am I able to do this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
while outerIndex<outerLoops:

    ts1 = time.time()
    ts2 = 0

    sqlReadRows = 'SELECT * FROM `user_session_0805` WHERE record_time >=%s AND record_time < %s ORDER BY record_time ASC LIMIT %s'
    readCur.execute(sqlReadRows,(startTime, maxTime, selectLimit)) 

    dataResults = readCur.fetchall()
    innerLoops = len(dataResults)
    innerIndex = 0

    batch = []
    while innerIndex<innerLoops:
        if len(dataResults) <100:
            for row in dataResults:
                if row:
                    batch.append(
                        row
                    )
        else:

            for i in range(innerIndex, innerIndex+100):
                if dataResults[i]:
                    batch.append(
                        dataResults
                    )
                else:
                    break

        innerIndex+=100

    sqlWrite = # Generate sql

    if batch:
        writeCur.executemany(sqlWrite, batch)
        cnx2.commit()
        startTime = batch[-1][1]
    ts2 = time.time()
    print 'Took %s secs to insert %s rows of data'%(int(ts2-ts1), len(batch))

    outerIndex+=1
```

I'm fairly new to Python, so I would appreciate any helpful advice too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the sql using this:

```
if batch:
        key =""
        key = '({})'.format(','.join(elem for elem in batch[0]))
        print key
        value ='({})'.format(','.join("'"+str(eleme)+"'" for eleme in batch[0].values()))
        print value
        sqlWrite = []
        sqlWrite.append("INSERT IGNORE INTO %s " %writeTable)
        sqlWrite.append("".join(key))
        sqlWrite.append(" VALUES ")
        sqlWrite.append("".join(value))
        sql="".join(sqlWrite)
        print sql
        if batch:
            writeCur.executemany(sql, batch)
            cnx2.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont do any modifications to the data, right? You can insert the SELECT result directly in a new Table:

```
INSERT INTO newTable
SELECT 
* 
FROM `user_session_0805` 
WHERE record_time >=%s 
AND record_time < %s 
ORDER BY record_time ASC 
LIMIT %s
```

You dont have to create the `newTable` first, MySQL will handle this for you. But you should do a

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newTable;
```

**Update**

You can export the values to a csv-file by using

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM `user_session_0805` 
WHERE record_time >=%s 
AND record_time < %s 
ORDER BY record_time ASC 
LIMIT %s
INTO OUTFILE 'c:/myFile.csv'
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to clarify that I am inserting the data into a table in a different server.

Comment: How do you communicate to that server? By csv-file?

Comment: I'm using two cursors with different connections.

Comment: Perhaps the FEDERATED storage-engine helps you here. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html